# Create HbaseConfiguration once in MapReduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am writing a map-reduce job in java.
I want to use external table for writing hbase increments object.
For that, I am creating new HbaseConfiguration.
I want to be able to create once and use in all mappers.
Any idea?

Comment: Just to clarify: I don't need to access the tables defined in the initial job configuration, but rather to access other table.

Answer (score 0):

The Job configuration is already passed to the mappers (and to the reducers) as a part of the context. You can access any HBase table with it.

```
Job job = new Job(HbaseConfiguration.create(), ...);
/* ... Rest of the job setup ... */
job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

Within your mapper setup method:

```
Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
HTable mytable = new HTable(config, "my_table_name");
....
```

---

You can even send your custom parameters or arguments so you can instantiate any kind of object you could need on your mappers:

```
Configuration config = HbaseConfiguration.create();
config.set("myStringParam", "customValue");
config.setStrings("myStringsParam", "customValue1", "customValue2", "customValue3");
config.setBoolean("myBooleanParam", true);
Job job = new Job(config, ...);
/* ... Rest of the job setup ... */
job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

Within your mapper setup method:

```
Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
String myStringParam = config.get("myStringParam");
String myBooleanParam = config.get("myBooleanParam");
```

BTW: I don't know why this question has so many downvotes, it's not a bad question.